# References and notes

Tags: database-recommendation

Please someone suggest me the books, sites for studying Oracle as well as MySQL which is easy to understand , analyze and explained with the examples.

Answer (score 1):

As for Oracle (can't help you with MySql) I would start with the 2 days books:

- [2 Day DBA](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/title.htm)
- [2 Day Developer](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDDDG/toc.htm)
- [2 Day Database + performance](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDPPT/title.htm)

That's enough reading for now. You should donwload a demo enviroment [VM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html) and play with it.
Sites, there are lots of them, but I found [oracle-base](https://oracle-base.com/) a good starting point.
And of course you could try to help here in StackOverflow and DBA Stack Exchange

Comment: How can I download all these notes

Comment: @MaheshDhokade There is a download button on the left, below the summary.